# Stop android browser from alerting "Device not connected to internet"

Tags: javascript, android, android-browser

Here is my problem -

I have a HTML page (page 1) which connects to another HTML page (page 2) in an iFrame. However this loading is done, say a minute after the page load completes.

ie. **page 1 -> wait 60 seconds -> open page 2 in iframe within page 1.**

However when this load occurs, the browser throws an alert that **network is not connected.**

***Is there something that can be done to prevent this behavior?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I found out that this behavior cannot be prevented from JS, but should be handled by the browser..